# 1 page, 20 sliders, 900 images, how to optimize for speed?

Tags: zurb-foundation, jekyll, orbit

I have a page for a real estate website with a list of all of the companies properties. Within each listing, there is a slider with ~50 images of that property.

DEMO: http://lexis250.github.io/groupecopley/properties/

The site is built with Jekyll and Foundation.

The problem is that this page is extremely heavy to load. I would like to implement a lazy load so the images are only loaded when they are requested. What is the most efficient way to go about doing this?

Code base on github:
https://github.com/lexis250/groupecopley

If I need to provide more information please let me know. I am a beginner.

Comment: What about paginating.

Comment: since you're using a slider I would check out http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
It has a lot of nice and easy to use features, one of which being a lazy loader.

Comment: When you load 40mb of video, asking how to optimize is clearly nonsense. Did you even eared about KISS ?

Comment: The video at http://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/Seoul-P1-4.mp4 is loading again and again (5 times in 10 minutes). This kills my data plan !!! You're not supposed to be only responsive, you can also be responsible !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can implement this using a combination of pagination and lazy loading. You can place 5 or 10 sliders on a page. Then each slider can use lazy loading to load images. As suggested in the comments as well look into `slick` here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Scroll down on the link you will see a feature for lazy loading along with code.

**Edit:**
You can also look into image compression and optimizing websites by gzip compression. Gzip compression is explained here: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/